# Faster UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, performance, uiwebview

I developed a game with HTML + CSS + jQuery. It's a simple Whac-a-mole game, which runs really well on the browser but is stuttering a bit on a UIWebView running on an iPad2.

I'm loading the UIWebView through a simple App I created, which has nothing else but that webview.

I find that the response to touches is quite poor and there's a bit of lag as well.

Do you guys know if there's a way to optimise it?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I think you'll have to add some profiling code to your app: find out where the heavy lifting is done.

Comment: Profile, definitely. It sounds like a javascript speed issue. You need to test this on an iPad 1, and make sure it flies on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the app runs better in the browser because the browser has the Nitro JavaScript engine. I'm not sure the UIWebView has access to it.

Answer (score 1):

Graphics loading and resizing are often huge performance hits. What if one of the moving graphics needs to be resized constantly? As the comment from Nick says - profile it. Profile the javascript.

Comment: Can you recommend a good/easy way to profile it on the iPad? It's a one-off App, it's only going to run on a single iPad2 throughout a conference, so no compatibility probs. Cheers